Gazebo Server error: Assertion `px != 0' failed. Libboost
I am working on a ROS project but when I do the simulation in Gazebo I get this error. It is inconsistent, sometimes it does not happen, but when it triggers it happens after different times (eg. after 2 minutes of simulation, after 10 minutes, etc).
gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::physics::Link; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::physics::Link*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-4] process has died [pid 8488, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -u --verbose -e ode /home/huro/catkin_ws/src/OnOrbitROS/src/cubesat/worlds/no_gravity.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/huro/.ros/log/87b34a98-1676-11ef-aa88-55bdc46032d8/gazebo-4.log].
log file: /home/huro/.ros/log/87b34a98-1676-11ef-aa88-55bdc46032d8/gazebo-4*.log

However, I don't use the library boost in my code, in any of the scripts that I have. Where I get a link is in a sensor plugin, and I make sure to manage the error with a try-catch and verify that all pointers are not null before using them. When the simulation stops I don't get any error message from my code, so I believe it is an internal Gazebo error. I was working on this project in a virtual machine before, with the same distributions, but I never got this error there, it started happening when I switched to native.
I have narrowed the source of the problem down to this method, where I try to update the position of the parent link of my sensor:
this->parentLink->SetWorldPose(new_world_pose);

I define the parentLink and other pointers in the onStart method:
void onStart(){
            // Get the sensor's parent link and the LVLH
            physics::WorldPtr world = physics::get_world(this->raySensor->WorldName());
            physics::LinkPtr parentLink;
            if (!world) {
                gzerr << "World pointer is null" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            try{
                for( const auto &model : world->Models() ){
                    if( model->GetName() == "orbitReference" ){
                        this->lvlh = model->GetLink("referenceSpaceCraft");     //Get the LVLH
                        if (!this->lvlh) {
                            gzerr << "LVLH link is null" << std::endl;
                            return;
                        }  
                    }
                    else if( model->GetName() == this->modelName ){
                        std::vector<physics::LinkPtr> links = model->GetLinks();    //Get the base link of the robot model
                        if (links.empty()) {
                            gzerr << "Model " << this->modelName << " has no links" << std::endl;
                            return;
                        }
                        this->modelBaseLink = links[0];
                        if( !this->modelBaseLink ) {
                            gzerr << "Model base link is null" << std::endl;
                            return;
                        }
                        parentLink = model->GetLink(this->raySensor->ParentName());
                        if( parentLink ){
                            this->parentLink = parentLink;  // Get the sensor's parent link
                        }
                        else{
                            gzerr << "Parent link is null for sensor " << this->raySensor->Name() << std::endl;
                            return;
                        }                    
                    }
                }
            } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                std::cerr << "Error getting links: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            } 
        }

And I use it in the onUpdate:
try{
                if( this->start ){
                    // Give time for the robot/spacecraft model to load
                    this->onStart();
                    this->start = false;
                }
                else{
                    if (!this->lvlh || !this->modelBaseLink || !this->parentLink) {
                        gzerr << "One or more required links are null" << std::endl;
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        // Update the orientation of the sensor as the LVLH: ensure the sensor is always facing the robot/spacecraft
                        if( this->sensorName == "1_1") {
                            ignition::math::Vector3d force(0, 1, 0);  //local of the sensor
                            ignition::math::Vector3d lvlh_y_direction = this->lvlh->WorldPose().Rot().RotateVector(force);
                            ignition::math::Vector3d position = this->modelBaseLink->WorldPose().Pos() + this->offset_model_sensor * lvlh_y_direction;
                            ignition::math::Pose3d new_world_pose(position, this->lvlh->WorldPose().Rot());
                            this->parentLink->SetWorldPose(new_world_pose);
                        }
                    }
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error reading scan: " << e.what() << std::endl;
} 

I have tried the solution proposed here, that has the same problem as me, but it didn't solve it.
Can someone help me? It is very difficult to debug. Any leads on what I should be trying? Thank you.
VERSIONS:

Ubuntu 20.04
Ros version: noetic
Gazebo version: 11.11.0. Copyright 2012, Released under the Apache 2 License
libboost-dev version: 1.71.0.0ubuntu2

